# Syntax question regarding function plotting in Mathematica.

Tags: graphing-functions

Y = (Sin[2 [Pi]t]) (1 + (1/5) Sin[6 [Pi]t] + (1/10) Sin[8 [Pi]t])

I'm trying to plot this function in Mathematica, however when I run
Plot[Y, {t, -15, 15}]  nothing will show up on the graph.

I think the problem is I'm entering the syntax wrong for all the trig functions?

Sorry I'm new to Mathematica.
Thank you for any help!
Joe

Comment: Thank you @Guest 86, I'll try that.

Comment: Ah I deleted the comment, sorry - I said that Y is evaluated once for some t when it's defined. Y[t_]:= (Sin[2 Pi t]) (1 + (1/5) Sin[6 Pi t] + (1/10) Sin[8 Pi t]) makes it a function which can be used in Plot[Y[x], {x,-15,15}]

Comment: @guest86
In[116]:= 
Y[t_] := (Sin[
    2 \[Pi]t]) (1 + (1/5) Sin[6 \[Pi]t] + (1/10) Sin[8 \[Pi]t])

During evaluation of In[116]:= SetDelayed::write: Tag Times in (Sin[6.28319 sin^2 x] (1+1/5 Sin[18.8496 sin^2 x]+1/10 Sin[25.1327 sin^2 x]))[t_] is Protected. >>

Out[116]= $Failed

Comment: If you used copy-paste, there might be some hidden space (Or another char) there, somewhere. Try retyping Y[t_]:= (Sin[2 Pi t]) (1 + (1/5) Sin[6 Pi t] + (1/10) Sin[8 Pi t]) manually.

Comment: @guest86
Thanks for all the responses
I just retyped it all, no extra spaces or anything and get:

In[120]:= 
Y[t_] := (Sin[
    2 \[Pi]t]) (1 + (1/5) Sin[6 \[Pi]t] + (1/10) Sin[8 \[Pi]t])

During evaluation of In[120]:= SetDelayed::write: Tag Times in (Sin[6.28319 sin^2 x] (1+1/5 Sin[18.8496 sin^2 x]+1/10 Sin[25.1327 sin^2 x]))[t_] is Protected. >>

Out[120]= $Failed

Comment: @guest86
I just closed the program and reopend it and copy pasted what I've been entering... Of course now there is no error haha. It still wont plot anything though.

In[2]:= Y[
  t_] := (Sin[
    2 \[Pi]t]) (1 + (1/5) Sin[6 \[Pi]t] + (1/10) Sin[8 \[Pi]t])

In[4]:= Plot[Y[t_], {t, -15, 15}]

Out[4]= a blank graph

Comment: @Joe Try clearing all your variables.  `Clear[x,t,Y]`  Then make your $Y$ function again, using the delayed evaluation `Y[t_] := (your function in t)` (The `t` should turn green in your expression.)  Then do your plot again: `Plot[ Y[t] , {t , -15, 15} ]`.

Comment: @Joe The reason what you have written there isn't working is the `_` after `t` in your `Plot`.  `_` is used in conjunction with `:=` to denote a delayed evaluation, meaning that it won't evaluate what's on the RHS of the `:=` until `Y` is called with an argument.  When you put `t` in `Y[t]` in the `Plot`, you're actually fixing a `t`, so there's no need for `_`.  (You're *calling* a function, not *making* a function.)

Comment: @Guest86
Thank you! I needed a space in between the pi and t's in the formula. Also, thank you for showing me how to enter formulas as functions correctly.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber
Thank you! The plot is working great now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the brackets from around $\pi$ and use parentheses instead (or the times operator *).

So, like this:

In[1]:= Y = (Sin[2 (Pi)t]) (1 + (1/5) Sin[6 (Pi)t] + (1/10) Sin[8 (Pi)t]);

In[2]:= Plot[Y, {t, -15, 15}]

Comment: Y = (Sin[2*[Pi]*t]) (1 + (1/5) Sin[6*[Pi]*t] + (1/10) Sin[8*[Pi]*t])

Syntax::sntxf: "2*" cannot be followed by "[Pi]*t".

Syntax::tsntxi: "[Pi]" is incomplete; more input is needed.

Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .

Comment: [] is Mathematica's way of denoting functions. You are confusing the program writing [Pi]. If you need a grouping symbol to visually help you see the code, just use parentheses.

Comment: I'm entering them as esc p esc but when I copy paste them here it changes them to [Pi]. Is the esc p esc method ok?

Comment: @Joe yes that works. `\[Pi]` is the ASCII form of the Pi symbol. Are you connecting the Pi and the t close together? You need a space between them (`\[Pi] t`, *not* `\[Pi]t`) otherwise Mathematica will interpret the pair as a single symbol/variable.

Comment: @Sasha
THANK YOU!!!! This was the problem I had from the beginning... I needed a space between the pi and t.